# Mongolab: search for multiple documents by _id

Tags: mlab

I use MongoLab as a backend store for an angular app. I have a collection with documents and I have an array of _ids. Is it possible to retrieve all documents from the collection  that have an _id value that is present in the array?

I am looking for a REST call since I have a Angular app that requests data from the MongoLab REST api

Thanks!

Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the $in operator: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/. If you need any additional assistance crafting the query feel free to email us at support AT mongolab dot com.

Cheers!